# How can I get the first and the last word or character between which a special character fall in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's consider an string named **calc** which is defined as :

```
const calc = "Find 2&3";
```

And now a function named **parse()**, which does something like this :

```
console.log( parse(calc) );
// => First character is 2 while last character is 3
```

So, we observed that the **parse()** function figured out the first and last character between which the **&** fall. So, can the **parse()** be made ? If yes how ? If no any alternative ? What if there are multiples ?

e.g.

```
const calc = "Find 2&3 , 4&5 , 6&7";
console.log( parse(calc) );
// => First character is 2 while last character is 3 
// => First character is 4 while last character is 5
// =>  First character is 6 while last character is 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.match()` with a regular expression to match the 1st character and last character, which are not a space (`\S`) and have `&` between them (more info at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HkZ4dV/1)).

**Note**: the result of the match is an array that contains the matched string, and the two capture groups results. I use destructuring to assing them to `first` and `last`.

```js
const calc = 'Find 2&3';

const [, first, last] = calc.match(/(\S)\S*&\S*(\S)/);

console.log(first, last);
```

To get all matches you can use [`String.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) (not supported by IE or Edge). The result would be an iterator, which you can spread to an array containing the sub-arrays with the results.

```js
const calc = 'Find 2&3 , 4&5 , 6&7';

const matches = calc.matchAll(/(\S)\S*&\S*(\S)/g);

console.log([...matches]);
```

Comment: what if there are multiple, not single ?

Comment: Is their any way to console all the values one by one ( if multiple ) ?